# Need a Mysql query of following table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 3 table

Table1

```
---------------------------
Cid | Name
-----------------------------
C1 |  Customer 1
------------------------------
C2 |  Customer2
------------------------------
C3 |  Customer3
```

Table2

```
---------------------------
Cid | ItemId
-----------------------------
C1 |  i1
------------------------------
C2 |  i1
-----------------------------
C1 |  i2
------------------------------
C2 |  i3
-----------------------------
C1 |  i4
------------------------------
C2 |  i4
-----------------------------
C1 |  i5
------------------------------
```

Table3

```
---------------------------
ItemId | price
-----------------------------
I1  |  10
------------------------------
I2  |  14
------------------------------
I3  |  15
------------------------------
I4  |  16
------------------------------
I5  |  20
------------------------------
```

Need a 
Select query to get result

```
Cid | CustomerName | totalprice
----------------------------------------------------
C1 | Customer 1 | 60
----------------------------------------------------
C2 | Customer 2 | 31
----------------------------------------------------
C3 | Customer 3 | 0
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT t1.CID,t1.NAME,SUM(t3.prize)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.CID = t2.CID
INNER JOIN on Table3 t3 ON t2.ItemID = t3.ItemID
GROUP BY t1.CID,t1.NAME
```